# xamarin form master detail menu page, link text not display

Tags: xamarin, master-detail

I create new xamarin forms project with master detail template.

When I try to run the project using release configuration the link text in drawer is not displayed but when I using debug configuration, the link text is displayed correctly.

Pictures for detail.

[image]

**using release configuration**

[image]

**using debug configuration**
[image]

Comment: Try to change linking in Android Project Properties.

Comment: in my previous project I use SDK and User Assemblies for linking, then I try to change it to SDK Assemblies only. the text menu appears but the selected link still not appear